# How to multiply all the elements in a list

Tags: list, multiplication

How can I multiply all the elements in a list by themselves (python 2.7)?

for instance:

b=[2,3,4]

output: 2*3*4=24

Comment: what have you wrote? in what language?

Comment: I edited. it's python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

*simple one*

```
mul=1
for i in b:
    mul =mul*i
print mul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
import functools
Result = functools.reduce(operator.mul, b, 1)
print(Result)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.

Comment: I doubt that this helps, or even works at all. Care to explain?